# The Android App works on Emulator and installs on Android Device but when I Open it, it shows blank screen and then Force Close

Tags: android, screen

I have created a small app and when I run it on Emulator, it runs perfect.

But, when I install it on a Device and start it, it shows Blank/Black Screen and then crashes with the message `The Application TOH(process my.own) has stopped unexpectedly`.

Not sure what am I doing wrong..

Please advise..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.own"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.3.4" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/background2"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".TOH"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Startgame"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".scoretell" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".details"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowPopUp"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the LogCat here.

Comment: It because error in your code. ...

Comment: your `supports-screens` tag is totally redundant... those values are set to `true` by default. You should remove it.

Comment: Also, you should look up the documentation for `versionCode`, because you are misinterpreting it. The value should correspond to the version of your *app*, not the version of the *android SDK*. You most likely didn't mean to it set to `versionCode="2.3.4"`, in other words...

Answer (score 0):

Look at what Logcat says when you run your app on emulator.

It has happened to me before that there is some "non-fatal" error (marked in orange in Logcat) when app runs on emulator, but apparently that error is fatal when app is deployed on a real device since it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following code from your activitys:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the Android Manifest (or any xml file for that matter) will not tell the story of your error. There are some things to fix in that file, but this may or may not be causing the error. What does the LogCat say in Eclipse? This can be accessed as a pane in Eclipse: Window > Show View > LogCat. It will likely have (red) error/text if you are debugging with USB connected to device. That will help the community see the specific error and it may even point you to a line number where your code is faltering. Just for reference, [this](http://fullroom.com/_blog/LogCatStep3.png) is what a logcat screen looks like.